# Are there any ways to calculate the uncertainty in a variable which does not have an exact solution?

Tags: error-analysis

Consider the uncertainty due to random error in the variable $x$ denoted by $x$. Furthermore, $x$ may be given by the function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3, ... , x_n)$ in which $x_1, x_2, x_3, ... , x_n$ are measurements independent of each other. The uncertainty in $x$ is given by the following:

$x = f(x_1, x_2, x_3, ... , x_n)$

$x = \sqrt{(x_1 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_1})^2+(x_2 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_2})^2 + (x_3 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_3})^2 + ... + (x_n \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_n})^2} $

However, now consider that the variable $x$ cannot have an exact solution, it has no closed form. Rather, it can be expressed as: $x = f(x, x_1, x_2, x_3, ... , x_n)$. Is it valid to say that the uncertainty in $x$ can be expressed as follows?

$x = f(x, x_1, x_2, x_3, ... , x_n)$

$x = \sqrt{(x \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x})^2+(x_1 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_1})^2+(x_2 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_2})^2 + (x_3 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_3})^2 + ... + (x_n \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_n})^2} $

Leading to:

$(x)^2 = {(x \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x})^2+(x_1 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_1})^2+(x_2 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_2})^2 + (x_3 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_3})^2 + ... + (x_n \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_n})^2} $

$(x)^2 - (x \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x})^2 = {(x_1 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_1})^2+(x_2 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_2})^2 + (x_3 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_3})^2 + ... + (x_n \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_n})^2} $

$(x)^2 - (x)^2 \cdot (\frac{∂f}{∂x})^2 = {(x_1 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_1})^2+(x_2 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_2})^2 + (x_3 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_3})^2 + ... + (x_n \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_n})^2} $

$(x)^2 (1-(\frac{∂f}{∂x})^2) = {(x_1 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_1})^2+(x_2 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_2})^2 + (x_3 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_3})^2 + ... + (x_n \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_n})^2} $

$x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{∂f}{∂x})^2}} \cdot \sqrt{{(x_1 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_1})^2+(x_2 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_2})^2 + (x_3 \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_3})^2 + ... + (x_n \cdot \frac{∂f}{∂x_n})^2}}  $

My question is: Are there any ways to calculate the uncertainty in a variable which does not have an exact solution?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of a variable of this type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rather, it can be expressed as: $x = f(x, x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots , x_n)$

That's a pretty misleading way to go about this. Instead, it's rather more honest to describe $x$ as the unique solution to the equation
$$
f(x, x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots , x_n) = 0
\tag 1
$$
given $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots , x_n$. Here the Implicit Function Theorem guarantees you the *existence* of a unique function $x = g(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots , x_n)$ that gives you $x$ as a function of the $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots , x_n$; this function might not be exact or analytical, and you might have no way of finding its value other than direct numerical solution of $(1)$, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

And, more importantly, the Implicit Function Theorem [gives you an explicit expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) for the derivatives of $g$ in terms of the derivatives of $f$. To see how you do this, first set $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ for convenience; in that language, the IFT guarantees the existence of $g(\mathbf x)$ for which
$$
f(g(\mathbf x),\mathbf x)\equiv 0
\tag 2
$$
for all $\mathbf x$. Then, you simply differentiate the identity $(2)$ with respect to $x_i$, which gives you
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \equiv 0,
$$
or in other words
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \Big/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.
\tag 3
$$
(In the Wikipedia proof, where $x$ stands for a multi-dimensional variable, the inverse $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^{-1}$ has been replaced by the inverse of a suitable Jacobian.)

Here equation $(3)$ gives you explicit, analytical expressions for the partial derivatives of the 'abstract' function $x = g(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots , x_n)$, and it is those expressions that should be used in the uncertainties, which simplifies to
$$
\delta x 
= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \delta x_i^2 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 \Big/ \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2}
= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \delta x_i^2 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2 }\Big/ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.
$$